# Implement taxonomy field on a custom react app

Tags: sharepoint-online, react

I am developing a custom react app. I need taxonomy and people picker controls on the app. Please let me know if this is possible and if yes, how.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Taxonomy Picker control based on React-Select, check the code in the article:

[react-taxonomypicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-taxonomypicker?activeTab=readme)

Create a People Picker control based on the solution:

[react-peoplepicker](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/366c28a57753ad410a1b50376dd5738186bbb6ed/samples/react-peoplepicker)